# Solving a simple ODE

Tags: equation-solving, differential-equations

I am trying to solve $y(x)' = \sqrt{y(x)}$ with initial condition $y(0)=0$ for $x\in \mathbb{R}$. I have tried this:

DSolve[{y'[x] == Sqrt[y[x]], y[0] == 0}, y[x], x]

but this gives

{{y[x] -> x^2/4}}

which is not the correct solution. The correct solution should be

$$
y(x)=
\begin{cases}
0 \quad\quad\quad x<c,\\
\frac{(x-c)^2}{4} \quad x \geq c,
\end{cases}
$$

where $c\geq0$.

Is there any way to get Mathematica to solve this correctly? Thanks!